# Does grunt-angular-architecture-graph support angular JS 4 application with typescript files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, database-design, gruntjs

I am trying to generate class/architectural diagram/graph from the source code.

https://github.com/lucalanca/grunt-angular-architecture-graph

The example/read.me file shows .js files in the gruntfile.js. Where as angularjs application I am building is having .ts files